# Determinant of $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are given by $m_{ij} = i^{n-j}$

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, determinant

Let $M_{n}$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are given by $m_{ij} = i^{n - j}$, I believe that we have that $\det(M_{1}) = 1$ and $\det(M_{n}) = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)! \cdot \det(M_{n-1})$ for $n \geq 2$. I have been trying to prove that this statement via induction on $n$, but I am unsure how to proceed with the induction step. If we assume that this is true for all $M_{k}$ up to some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider $M_{k+1}$ then certainly $M_{k}$ is a submatrix 
of $M_{k+1}$ but I am unsure how to use that information to my advantage as my linear algebra is a bit rusty.

Comment: are you sure you aren't confusing it with the Vandermonde matrix ? otherwise the determinant is trivially 0 (as Steve points out).

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I didn't encounter this matrix with the Vandermonde matrix in mind (or any knowledge of it for that matter). Unless I botched the code, that formula forked up to $n = 40$ or so.

Comment: Are you sure about the formula? I get 1, -1, -2, 12, 288, ... for the first few terms (which agrees with what you wrote up to sign). And yes, this is a Vandermonde determinant. The sign comes out of how many rows you have to swap to go from increasing to decreasing.

Comment: @SteveD Truthfully, I realized the determinant to be $| \det(M_{n}) |= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k!$, but thought the recurrence might be easier for induction purposes and it accounts for the sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your matrix:
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
2^{n-1} & 2^{n-2} & \cdots & 1\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
n^{n-1} & n^{n-2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Here is the Vandermonde version of this matrix:
\begin{equation}
B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & \cdots & 2^{n-2} & 2^{n-1} &\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
1 & \cdots & n^{n-2} & n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

It is well-known (and you can find plenty of proofs online) that 
$$ \det(B) = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k!$$

Since your columns are reversed, we get
$$ \det(B) = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k!$$

**EDIT**: The Vandermonde matrix has determinant
$$ \prod_{1 \mathop \le i \mathop < k \mathop \le n} \left({k - i}\right)$$
which is the same as what I wrote.

Comment: BTW, here is my personal favorite proof of the Vandermonde identity (you will need journal access and/or sci-hub to read the whole article, sadly): http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642196